# How do I findout whether a user is logged out from microsoft it's account?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I've a web application where I authenticate users from an Azure Active Directory through OAuth 2.0 code grant flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code.

How do I findout whether a user is logged out from microsoft it's account?

The reason I wanna track this is that I wanna be able to logout the user from my web application as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement is kind of invalid in today's modern auth scenario. A user does not log out from a "Microsoft Account" or any such service.

The Microsoft Account, AAD, AAD B2C are identity provider services that let applications, such as yours authenticate users to *your* app. At any point in time, a user could have is signed-into multiple apps from multiple devices. There is no service that will provide you these details about a user.

If you want the user to sign-out from your app, then they'd use your app's sign-out button/link.